# Where clause in hive over JSON data

Tags: json, hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I'm using JSONs as array in my file https://www.sitepoint.com/google-maps-json-file/  .I have used JSON serde to import data to the table as it has array like strucure and we cannot use JSON_TUPPLE and JSON_OBJECT UDF with array otherwise it gives nulls.

**Can't we use where clause over a HQL query having JSOn data? because everytime i query the table it gives the complete JSON data,it doesn't filter**

```
`hive> select *  from complex_json where markers[1].point="4578"
OK
[{"point":"1233","hometeam":"Lawrence Library","awayteam":"LUGip","markerimage":"images/red.png","information":"Linux users group meets second Wednesday of each month.","fixture":"Wednesday 7pm","capacity":"","previousscore":""},
{"point":"4578","hometeam":"Hamilton Library","awayteam":"LUGip HW SIG","markerimage":"images/white.png","information":"Linux users can meet the first Tuesday of the month to work out harward and configuration issues.","fixture":"Tuesday 7pm","capacity":"","previousscore":null}]
Time taken: 0.304 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)`
```

Answer (score 1):

Each record in your table is an array, So `select *` would bring the entire record as the output when the `where` clause finds a match.

Since your `where` clause is for `markers[1]`, you can use

```
select markers[1] from complex_json where markers[1].point="4578"
```

This would fetch only the desired JSON within the array.

Comment: If I will use markers[1] in my select class then there is no need to use it in where clause.even if I add it ,it will not work.but my concern here is to pick a particular row based on the value of point

Comment: From the wholesome records, you are picking one out based on the where clause which gives you an array. To retrieve the exact object from the array, this select is done. I don't understand how using it in select would solve the necessity of not using it in where

Comment: So it means every time i want to analyse some data first i have to see the JSON data which array i having which all values??It will not be like normal analyes with where/having conditional clauses we do in Hive.

Comment: If you do not know the array index you are looking for, you must make use of the [Lateral View](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView) and [explode()](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-explode) function to flatten your array. Once the array is flattened, each JSON will be a row.

Comment: I tried  Lateral View and explode() but it didn't gave me the desired results.                                                                                                                 `hive>  select adid ,adid1 from
    > (select markers.point as b,markers.hometeam as c from complex_json)a 
    > lateral view  explode(a.b) adtable  as adid
    > lateral view explode(a.c) adtable1 as adid1;
OK
1233 Lawrence Library
1233 Hamilton Library
4578 Lawrence Library
4578 Hamilton Library
`  For point values 1233 hamilton libraray doesn't exist however explode worked fine.

Comment: Just flatten the array and apply your selection criteria on the flattened JSON entries. For ex: `select entries from complex_json lateral view explode(markers) exploded_tbl as entries where entries.point="4578";`. Let me know if this solves.

Answer (score 0):

If columns are not specified in the select query, a raw Json will be pulled by Hive. As franklin has just explained.